# cannot append a featureCollection in typescript

Tags: javascript, geojson, typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
export interface Feature<T extends GeometryObject> extends GeoJsonObject
{
    type: 'Feature'
    geometry: T;
    properties: any;
    id?: string;
}

export interface FeatureCollection<T extends GeometryObject> extends GeoJsonObject
{
    type: 'FeatureCollection'
    features: Feature<T>[];
}
```

The I tried to append the following objects:

```
let geoJsonFeatureCollection:FeatureCollection<any> = { type: 'FeatureCollection',

features: [] 
};

console.log(geoJsonFeatureCollection);

for (var key in data){
    if (data[key].Volume>0){
        let Feature:Feature<any>;
        Feature['type'] = 'Feature';
        Feature['geometry'] = {'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [data[key].YO, data[key].XO],
    };
    Feature['properties'] =  {'origin_city': data[key].Origin,
    'origin_lat' : data[key].YO,
    'origin_lon' : data[key].XO,
    'destination_city' : data[key].Destination,
    'destination_lat' : data[key].Y,
    'destination_lon' : data[key].X,
    'volume' : data[key].Volume

};
    geoJsonFeatureCollection['Features'].push(Feature);
}
}
```

but looks like its not working ..